# Change package name without new install

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I changed id value in config.xml for change package name.
I build my project and install in device.
but no update old version.
new app installed to device and exist two app of project in device.
how to change package name without new install app in device ?
I want to update old version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID of an application is its package name. Different package name means different application. If you want to update an app you must not change its package name.